# "Uncaught Error: Zone already loaded." during karma test

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, karma-runner

All I want is to be able to load my typescript files into the browser's debugger when I run unit tests with Karma. If I remove karma-typescript, the tests run, but I can only debug with the transpiled javascript. With karma-typescript, I get the above error. What do I need to do to debug my typescript files while using karma?

Here is my karma conf that is used for tests.

```
const conf = require('./gulp.conf');

module.exports = function (config) {
const configuration = {
basePath: '../',
singleRun: false,
autoWatch: true,
logLevel: 'INFO',
junitReporter: {
  outputDir: 'test-reports'
},
browsers: [
  'Chrome'
],
frameworks: [
  'jasmine',
  'karma-typescript'
],
files: [
  { pattern: "src/**/*.ts" },
  conf.path.src('index.spec.js')
],
preprocessors: {
  [conf.path.src('index.spec.js')]: [
    'webpack'
  ],
  "**/*.ts": ['karma-typescript']
},
reporters: ['progress', 'coverage', 'karma-typescript'],
coverageReporter: {
  type: 'html',
  dir: 'coverage/'
},
webpack: require('./webpack-test.conf'),
webpackMiddleware: {
  noInfo: true
},
plugins: [
  require('karma-jasmine'),
  require('karma-junit-reporter'),
  require('karma-coverage'),
  require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
  require('karma-webpack'),
  require('karma-typescript')
]
};

  config.set(configuration);
};
```

Here is my webpack conf that is used for tests.

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const conf = require('./gulp.conf');
module.exports = {
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /.json$/,
        loaders: [
          'json-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /.ts$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'tslint-loader',
        enforce: 'pre'
      },
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loaders: [
          'ts-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /.html$/,
        loaders: [
          'html-loader'
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
      /angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)(esm(\\|\/)src|src)(\\|\/)linker/,
      conf.paths.src
    ),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      options: {
        resolve: {},
        ts: {
          configFileName: 'tsconfig.json'
        },
        tslint: {
          configuration: require('../tslint.json')
        }
      },
      debug: true
    }),
    new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
      filename: null,
      test: /\.(ts|js)($|\?)/i
    })
  ],
  devtool: 'source-map',
  resolve: {
    extensions: [
      '.webpack.js',
      '.web.js',
      '.js',
      '.ts'
    ]
  }
};
```

Here is my webpack conf that is used for running the app.

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const conf = require('./gulp.conf');
const path = require('path');

const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const FailPlugin = require('webpack-fail-plugin');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
const fileLoader = require('file-loader');

module.exports = {
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /.json$/,
        loaders: [
          'json-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /.ts$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'tslint-loader',
        enforce: 'pre'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(css|scss)$/,
        loaders: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader',
          'postcss-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loaders: [
          'ts-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /.html$/,
        loaders: [
          'html-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
        loader: "file-loader?name=/public/images/[name].[ext]"

      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
    FailPlugin,
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: conf.path.src('index.html')
    }),
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
      /angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)(esm(\\|\/)src|src)(\\|\/)linker/,
      conf.paths.src
    ),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      options: {
        postcss: () => [autoprefixer],
        resolve: {},
        ts: {
          configFileName: 'tsconfig.json'
        },
        tslint: {
          configuration: require('../tslint.json')
        }
      },
      debug: true
    })
  ],
  devtool: 'source-map',
  output: {
    path: path.join(process.cwd(), conf.paths.tmp),
    filename: 'index.js'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [
      '.webpack.js',
      '.web.js',
      '.js',
      '.ts'
    ]
  },
  entry: `./${conf.path.src('index')}`
};
```

Please let me know what other info or code you would like.

Comment: I am encountering the same issue trying to migrate to @angular/cli 1.0.0-rc.0 (from 1.0.0-beta.26)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my case (migrating to @angular/cli 1.0.0-rc.0 from 1.0.0-beta.26) I fixed it by removing

```
import './polyfills.ts';
```

from `src/test.ts`, as it now seems to be added by *ng* based on `"polyfills": "polyfills.ts"` in `angular-cli.json`.

Here is the beta->rc [upgrade guide](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-rc-update) listing other changes needed.

Comment: The exact same solution *just* worked for me.  Thank you.

Comment: Marked as answer because it prompted me to rebuild my project using angular cli instead of Yeoman, and then tests worked.

Comment: I didnt find angular-cli.json flile. Where is the exactly location or i have to create new one ?

Answer (score 0):

I fix my problem as below.

Install the lower version of firebase using this command

**npm install angularfire2@5.0.0-rc.4**

then install npm

**npm install**

Then remove this line on src / main.ts

```
import  './polyfills';
```

it work for me. I just want share it. I hope it will help someone.